# What's $E[X - E[X | Y] |Y]$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value

I'm trying to figure out what $E[X - E[X | Y] |Y]$ equals to. Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables, I thought that

$E[X - E[X | Y] |Y] = E[X |Y] - E[E[X|Y]|Y] = E[X|Y] - YE[X|Y]$

Is the above correct?

Comment: I think  $ E[E[X|Y]|Y] = E[X]$

Comment: @user158565 From law of iterated expectation, we know that $E[E[X|Y]] = X$. Hmm..why do you think that $E[E[X|Y]|Y] = X$ as well?

Comment: If $E[E[X|Y]|Y]=E_Y[E_X[X|Y]|Y]$ then $E[E[X|Y]|Y] = E[E[X|Y]] = E[X]$. If $E[E[X|Y]|Y]=E_X[E_X[X|Y]|Y]$, then $E[E[X|Y]|Y] = E[X|Y]] $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ is a function of $Y$ (but not $X$), it is constant when taken conditional on $Y$.  Hence, you have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E} \Big[X - \mathbb{E}[X | Y] \Big| Y \Big] 
&= \mathbb{E}[X |Y] - \mathbb{E} \Big[ \mathbb{E}[X|Y] \Big| Y \Big] \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}[X |Y] - \mathbb{E}[X |Y] = 0. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, apply linearity of expectation:
$$E[X-E[X|Y]|Y]=E[X|Y]-E[E[X|Y]|Y]$$
The first term needs no further modification, while he second term can be simplified. $E[X|Y]$ is a function of $Y$, and $X$ is already cancelled out in the expectation. So, we actually have $E[f(Y)|Y]$, in which $f(Y)$, i.e. $E[X|Y]$ gets out, leaving us with
$E[X|Y]-E[X|Y]=0$.